# Утечка памяти при инициализации VC и Storyboard Через код

Tags: xcode, swift, утечка-памяти

Создал функцию которая отображает новый ViewController вот так:

```
let newVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: name, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id) as? VCProtocol
        currentVC?.present(newVC! as! UIViewController,animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Но с таким написанием VC не деинициализируется. deinit не вызывается. Как выгрузить из памяти не нужный контроллер?

Comment: Он и не должен деинициализироваться при present(_:animated:completion:)

Comment: То есть невозможно как то убирать из памяти уже не используемые ViewControllerы без NavigationControllera?

Answer (score 1):

Это не является утечкой и контроллер не должен деинициализироваться.

Но если вы хотите именно заменить на новый, используйте следующий подход:

```
let window = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!
let prewController = window.rootViewController
for element in window.subviews {
    element.removeFromSuperview()
}
window.rootViewController = newVC //Заменяете контроллер
prewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
    prewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
})
```

Comment: Именно этого я и искал. Спасибо, что сказали, что это не утечка. Код полезный!